# How do I remove the border around this image in Bookdown?

Tags: r, bookdown, border-layout

I am writing a technical report in Bookdown to be output to html format. I have inserted an image on the cover page and wish to remove the border. See image here:

[image: Border around image]

The code to insert the image is here:

````
```{r, fig.align='center', echo=FALSE}
knitr::include_graphics('./images/Solar panel.jpg')
```
````

I also inserted this code in the **style.css** script:

```
img {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

For reference, here is the **_output.yml** script:

```
bookdown::bs4_book:
  css: style.css
  theme:
    primary: "#231EDC"
    secondary: "#D2D1F8"
    border-width: "0px"
    border-color: "#FFFFFF"
    blockquote-border-color: "#FFFFFF"
```

Unfortunately, the border is still visible. Does anyone know how I can remove the border, or at least hide it.

Comment: I am not sure, but can you experiment? Please remove border-width, border-color and blockquote-border-color from the _output.yml and see if the border still remains.

Comment: I've just removed those lines, but the border is still there. I've done lots of experiments trying to isolate what is causing it with no luck so far :(

Answer (score 0):

Removing the border property for `inline-figure` class will solve your case.

So simply add this code to your *style.css* file

**style.css**

```
.inline-figure {
  border: none !important;
}
```